# Click on text to copy a link to the clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so that users using my script can just click on an ID from a specific website and it will copy a link to their clipboard with the text they clicked on. For example, I click on the text 1510970 on http://www.myurl.com/ and it copies a link http://www.myurl.com/viewReport.php?id= with the ID, so when I paste my copied content, it should look like http://www.myurl.com/viewReport.php?id=1510970.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to ensure compatibility with all major browsers, you can use the following workaround:

- Create a `<textarea>` element to be appended to the document.
- Set its value to the string that we want to copy to the clipboard.
- Append the `<textarea>` element to the HTML document.
- Use `HTMLInputElement.select()` to select the contents of the `<textarea>` element.
- Use `Document.execCommand('copy')` to copy the contents of the `<textarea>` to the clipboard.
- Remove the `<textarea>` element from the document.

```js
const copyToClipboard = str => {
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = str;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);
};

const url ='http://www.myurl.com/viewReport.php?id=';

document.getElementById('myItem').addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
  let myUrl =  url + e.target.dataset.page_id;
  copyToClipboard( myUrl );
  alert(myUrl + ' copied to clipboard!')
});
```

```html
<div id="myItem" data-page_id="1510970">1510970</div>
```

> **STYLE** : Injecting a `textarea` in your HTML can cause some rendering issues. To avoid them, use CSS to hide the element, give it an absolute position, and negative y-coordinates. (These are just examples.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it

```js
function copyText(){
    var url = "http://www.myurl.com/viewReport.php?id=";
    var text = document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML;
    var textCopy = document.getElementById("myText");
    textCopy.value = url + text;    
    document.execCommand("copy");
    }
```

```html
<div id="myText" onclick="copyText()">Text you want to copy</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It only copies "Text you want to copy"; it doesn't append a link to it before copying it to the clipboard.