# I have a HTML table converted from CSV with JavaScript. I want to add hyperlinks to the rows in the second column

Tags: javascript, html, csv

Here's the JavaScript embed in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JS Read CSV</title>
    <style>
      * {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      table {
        margin: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      table tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #f2f2f2;
      }
      table td {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- FILE PICKER -->
    <input type="file" accept=".csv" id="picker">

    <!-- DISPLAY CSV HERE -->
    <table id="table"></table>

    <script>
      // Create a function to copy the text to clipboard
      const copyToClipboard = str => {
        const el = document.createElement("textarea");
        el.value = str;
        document.body.appendChild(el);
        el.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(el);
      };

      window.onload = () => {
        // FILE READER + HTML ELEMENTS
            var reader = new FileReader(),
                picker = document.getElementById("picker"),
                table = document.getElementById("table");

            // READ CSV ON FILE PICK
            picker.onchange = ()=> reader.readAsText(picker.files[0]);

            // READ THE CSV FILE & GENERATE HTML
            reader.onloadend = () => {
                // ENTIRE CSV FILE
                let csv = reader.result;

                //CLEAR HTML TABLE 
                table.innerHTML = "";

                // SPLIT INTO ROWS
                let rows = csv.split("\r\n");

                // LOOP THROUGH ROWS + SPLIT COLUMNS 
                for (let row of rows) {
                let cols = row.match(/(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\")|([^\",]+)/g);
                if (cols != null) {
                    let tr = table.insertRow();
                    for (let col of cols) {
                    let td = tr.insertCell();
                    td.innerHTML = col.replace(/(^"|"$)/g, "");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    };
    </script>
</body>
```

I want to add hyperlinks to the rows in the 2nd column. When you click on the hyperlink text, I want the JavaScript to copy the link to the clipboard.

I found the following JavaScript at [Click on text to copy a link to the clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625169/click-on-text-to-copy-a-link-to-the-clipboard). How can I add it to the above JavaScript embed in HTML?

```
const copyToClipboard = str => {
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = str;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);
};

const url ='http://www.myurl.com/viewReport.php?id=';

document.getElementById('myItem').addEventListener('click', function(e){ 
  let myUrl =  url + e.target.dataset.page_id;
  copyToClipboard( myUrl );
  alert(myUrl + ' copied to clipboard!')
});
```

```
<div id="myItem" data-page_id="1510970">1510970</div>
```

The CSV file looks like this:

```
# No, Position, Duration, Comment
1,"00:02:09:120","00:00:03:000","Hello"
2,"00:10:45:559","00:00:03:000","Goodbye"
```

Comment: let copyText =  function copyText(){
    var url = "http://www.myurl.com/viewReport.php?id=";
    var text = document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML;
    var textCopy = document.getElementById("myText");
    textCopy.value = url + text;    
    document.execCommand("copy");
    } add in your current js when you are adding td use td.addEventListener("click", copyText );

Comment: Sorry Nisha, I have very little programming skills. I don't how to integrate your code. I want the HTML page to work offline (not on the server). The copyToClipboard code above is only an example of what I found but I don't know if it's suitable for my task. I'm trying to also study the following page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995528/add-links-to-all-cells-in-column-of-html-table

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>JS Read CSV</title>
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        table {
            margin: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #f2f2f2;
        }

        table td {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- FILE PICKER -->
    <input type="file" accept=".csv" id="picker">

    <!-- DISPLAY CSV HERE -->
    <table id="table"></table>

    <script>
        // Create a function to copy the text to clipboard
        const copyToClipboard = str => {
            const el = document.createElement("textarea");
            el.value = str;
            document.body.appendChild(el);
            el.select();
            document.execCommand("copy");
            document.body.removeChild(el);
        };

        window.onload = () => {
            // FILE READER + HTML ELEMENTS
            var reader = new FileReader(),
                picker = document.getElementById("picker"),
                table = document.getElementById("table");

            // READ CSV ON FILE PICK
            picker.onchange = () => reader.readAsText(picker.files[0]);

            // READ THE CSV FILE & GENERATE HTML
            reader.onloadend = () => {
                // ENTIRE CSV FILE
                let csv = reader.result;

                //CLEAR HTML TABLE 
                table.innerHTML = "";

                // SPLIT INTO ROWS
                let rows = csv.split("\r\n");

                // LOOP THROUGH ROWS + SPLIT COLUMNS 
                for (let row of rows) {
                    let cols = row.match(/(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\")|([^\",]+)/g);
                    if (cols != null) {
                        let tr = table.insertRow();
                        for (let col of cols) {
                            let td = tr.insertCell();
                            td.innerHTML = col.replace(/(^"|"$)/g, "");

                        }
                    }
                }
                // adding click event
                const elements = document.querySelectorAll("#table td:nth-child(2)");
                //Then, we loop through those elements
                for (let i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    elements[i].addEventListener("click", copyClipboard)
                }
            };
        };


        let copyClipboard = function copyClipboard() {
            // Get the text field
            let copyText = event.target.innerHTML;
            // Copy the text inside the text field
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
            // Alert the copied text
            console.log("Copied the text: " + copyText);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I hope it will work but if you want to apply copyclipboard on a different column const elements = document.querySelectorAll("#table td:nth-child(2)"); change 2 in nth-child(2) which means 2nd row  like 3 or something so it will apply on that column you can check result in console by clicking that cell.

Comment: This works very well, thank you so much Nisha for generously offering your help and time to solve this. I use it as an offline file and I get a message pop-up message This file wants to See text and images copied to the clipboard but that's fine, I just click OK to unblock.  Thank you for explaining the const elements nth-child. I have created a variable for the nth-child for a drop-down column menu

Comment: let columnSelect = document.getElementById("column-select");
columnSelect.addEventListener("change", () => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(`#table td:nth-child(${columnSelect.value})`);
    for (let i = 1; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].addEventListener("click", copyClipboard);
    }
});

Comment: Please provide details in your answer, not only code.

Comment: @Nisha: would you add some explanatory text into this answer? Code only isn't as easy for future readers to learn from.